# Change the tabs text title in dynamic

Tags: android

I have a tablayout with four tabs under viewpager. I want to change the text title when i slide the tab. My problem is i can't handle tab respectively.

For instance the four tabs title are 1、2、3、4 , when i slide it will show like 1、9、3、4 or 1、2、9、4...

but it is 7、9、7、7 or 7、7、9、7...in my case

I try to write it on onTabUnselected function . Obviously i don't have the variable to control it.

What can i do next ?

Part of the program:

```
private ViewPager viewPager;

viewPager.addOnPageChangeListener(new TabLayout.TabLayoutOnPageChangeListener(tabLayoutHomePage));
        tabLayoutHomePage.setOnTabSelectedListener(new TabLayout.OnTabSelectedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onTabSelected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {
                int id=tab.getPosition();
                switch (id){
                    case 0:
                        tab.setText("9");
                        break;
                    case 1:
                        tab.setText("9");
                        break;
                    case 2:
                        tab.setText("9");
                        break;
                    case 3:
                        tab.setText("9");
                        break;
                }
                    viewPager.setCurrentItem(tab.getPosition());
            }

            @Override
            public void onTabUnselected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {
                int id=tab.getPosition();
                switch (id){
                    case 0:
                        tab.setText("7");
                        break;
                    case 1:
                        tab.setText("7");
                        break;
                    case 2:
                        tab.setText("7");
                        break;
                    case 3:
                        tab.setText("7");
                        break;
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onTabReselected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {

            }
        });
```

The original declare four tabs title

```
tabLayoutHomePage = (TabLayout) view.findViewById(R.id.tabLayoutHomePage);
    tabLayoutHomePage.addTab(tabLayoutHomePage.newTab().setText(R.string.bloodPressure));
    tabLayoutHomePage.addTab(tabLayoutHomePage.newTab().setText(R.string.bloodSugar));
    tabLayoutHomePage.addTab(tabLayoutHomePage.newTab().setText(R.string.bodyWeight));
    tabLayoutHomePage.addTab(tabLayoutHomePage.newTab().setText(R.string.vaccine));
    tabLayoutHomePage.setTabGravity(TabLayout.GRAVITY_FILL);
```

Comment: So exactly what you want is it 1,9,3,4 or 7,9,7,7

Comment: it's 1、9、3、4   
7、9、7、7 just for test
i got the solution,thanks for your attenition.

Comment: any time buddy always welcome

Answer (score 26, accepted):

try this

```
tabLayoutHomePage.getTabAt(position).setText("new Text");
```

Comment: You woke me up. Why i did not expect , thank you @Mh Sami

Comment: nice,this slove my question. ThankYou very much

Answer (score 0):

This should also work

`mSlidingTabLayout.setTabText(position,name)`